# I updated Antergos and now my VM's won't launch

Tags: arch-linux

I recently updated my Antergos install and it seems to have broken a lot of things. One of the more important things is Qemu/KVM. I've read through the log, but I don't really understand it.

Here's the log:

```
2019-03-18 17:42:57.774+0000: starting up libvirt version: 5.1.0, qemu version: 3.1.0, kernel: 5.0.2-arch1-1-ARCH, hostname: andrew-laptop
LC_ALL=C \
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl \
HOME=/home/andrew \
USER=andrew \
LOGNAME=andrew \
QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=spice \
/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
-name guest=boxes-unknown,debug-threads=on \
-S \
-object secret,id=masterKey0,format=raw,file=/home/andrew/.config/libvirt/qemu/lib/domain-4-boxes-unknown/master-key.aes \
-machine pc-i440fx-3.1,accel=kvm,usb=off,dump-guest-core=off \
-cpu host \
-m 8207 \
-realtime mlock=off \
-smp 8,sockets=1,cores=4,threads=2 \
-uuid 59aeca01-cdfa-42d9-8756-2727f811b1b6 \
-no-user-config \
-nodefaults \
-chardev socket,id=charmonitor,fd=24,server,nowait \
-mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control \
-rtc base=utc,driftfix=slew \
-global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=delay \
-no-hpet \
-no-shutdown \
-global PIIX4_PM.disable_s3=1 \
-global PIIX4_PM.disable_s4=1 \
-boot strict=on \
-device ich9-usb-ehci1,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5.0x7 \
-device ich9-usb-uhci1,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=0,bus=pci.0,multifunction=on,addr=0x5 \
-device ich9-usb-uhci2,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=2,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5.0x1 \
-device ich9-usb-uhci3,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=4,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5.0x2 \
-device virtio-serial-pci,id=virtio-serial0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6 \
-device usb-hub,id=hub0,bus=usb.0,port=1 \
-device usb-ccid,id=ccid0,bus=usb.0,port=2 \
-drive file=/home/andrew/.local/share/gnome-boxes/images/boxes-unknown,format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-0,cache=writeback \
-device ide-hd,bus=ide.0,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-0-0,id=ide0-0-0,bootindex=1,write-cache=on \
-drive if=none,id=drive-ide0-1-0,readonly=on \
-device ide-cd,bus=ide.1,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-1-0,id=ide0-1-0 \
-netdev user,id=hostnet0 \
-device rtl8139,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:b2:d2:71,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 \
-chardev spicevmc,id=charsmartcard0,name=smartcard \
-device ccid-card-passthru,chardev=charsmartcard0,id=smartcard0,bus=ccid0.0 \
-chardev pty,id=charserial0 \
-device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 \
-chardev spicevmc,id=charchannel0,name=vdagent \
-device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=1,chardev=charchannel0,id=channel0,name=com.redhat.spice.0 \
-chardev spiceport,id=charchannel1,name=org.spice-space.webdav.0 \
-device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=2,chardev=charchannel1,id=channel1,name=org.spice-space.webdav.0 \
-device usb-tablet,id=input0,bus=usb.0,port=3 \
-device usb-mouse,id=input1,bus=usb.0,port=4 \
-device usb-kbd,id=input2,bus=usb.0,port=5 \
-spice port=0,disable-ticketing,image-compression=off,gl=on,rendernode=/dev/dri/renderD128,seamless-migration=on \
-device virtio-vga,id=video0,max_outputs=1,bus=pci.0,addr=0x2 \
-device intel-hda,id=sound0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4 \
-device hda-duplex,id=sound0-codec0,bus=sound0.0,cad=0 \
-chardev spicevmc,id=charredir0,name=usbredir \
-device usb-redir,chardev=charredir0,id=redir0,bus=usb.0,port=6 \
-chardev spicevmc,id=charredir1,name=usbredir \
-device usb-redir,chardev=charredir1,id=redir1,bus=usb.0,port=1.1 \
-chardev spicevmc,id=charredir2,name=usbredir \
-device usb-redir,chardev=charredir2,id=redir2,bus=usb.0,port=1.2 \
-chardev spicevmc,id=charredir3,name=usbredir \
-device usb-redir,chardev=charredir3,id=redir3,bus=usb.0,port=1.3 \
-device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x7 \
-sandbox on,obsolete=deny,elevateprivileges=deny,spawn=deny,resourcecontrol=deny \
-msg timestamp=on
2019-03-18 17:42:57.774+0000: Domain id=4 is tainted: host-cpu
char device redirected to /dev/pts/0 (label charserial0)
2019-03-18 17:42:57.873+0000: shutting down, reason=failed
```